# Managing files after creating an RStudio EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

After following this simple tutorial http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ I have setup an RStudio environment on EC2, and I'm able to run R code :)

The files that I create through RStudio - I'm not sure exactly where these files reside - can I view them on the web somewhere / can I access them via the AWS console?

Thanks!

Comment: Your two questions aren't related (except that they're both on EC2), so you should split them into separate questions.

Comment: Thanks - I've managed to solve 1 question, so only 1remains now